# Can't read undefined property for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I've run into some problems while creating solitaire game.

I'm working on the remaining deck, on which, when clicked, will be show remaining cards, so player can cycle through them while clicking on the deck.

The problem itself: when you click on the deck code generates a picture file name taking parameters from 2 different arrays.

The first time after click the card appears without any error, but when one tries to click for the second time error appears: "Cannot read property 'Taskai' of undefined".

Code:

```js
$.widget("Game.RemainingDeck", {
  options: {
    remainingDeck: []
  },

  _create: function() {
    var game = this;
    game.flipACard();

  },
  flipACard: function() {
    var i = 0;
    var game = this;

    $("#remDeck").click(function() {

      var remainDeck = game.options.remainingDeck;


      var remDeck = $('#remDeck');
      var oppenedCard = $('#openCard');
      var card = $('<div class=" card"></div> ');

      var imageName = remainDeck[i].Taskai + '_of_' + remainDeck[i].Simbolis + '.png';
      var imagePath = 'texture/' + imageName;

      card.css('background-image', 'url("' + imagePath + '")');

      if (i = game.options.remainingDeck.lenght) {
        aler("kaladë prasideda ið naujo");
      }

      i++;
      oppenedCard.append(card);

    });
  }
})
```

Comment: "if (i = game.options.remainingDeck.lenght) {" -- i see two errors here, 1st one is you should use == or === when comparing, 2nd one: length instead of lenght. fix them and try again?

Comment: The code does not define Taskai anywhere. Please create [mcve] without beginning each sentence with _So_ 
;) Hit F12 and fix the several console errors

Comment: @krankuba first one is not a problem. But second is

Comment: @krankuba well spotted - the typo, however `if (i=something)` is a valid test if you want false when something is falsy AND assign to `i`. Also alert is misspelled btw.

Comment: You also have an `aler("kaladë prasideda ið naujo");` im it should be an `alert`

Comment: @krankuba thanks for your ideas, length was fixed and if statement was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` needs to be an outer var, otherwise it is `0` every time the click handler runs.

Also, I don't think the click handler should be attached in `.flipcard()`, otherwise it will be attached over and over, every time `flipCard()` is run. Try attaching  the click handler in `.create_()`.

```
$.widget("Game.RemainingDeck", {
    options: {
        remainingDeck: []
    },
    _create: function() {
        var game = this;
        var i = 0;
        $("#remDeck").on('click', function() {
            $('#openCard').append($('<div class=" card"></div>').css('background-image', 'url("texture/' + game.options.remainingDeck[i].Taskai + '_of_' + game.options.remainingDeck[i].Simbolis + '.png")'));
            if(i === game.options.remainingDeck.length) {
                alert("kaladë prasideda ið naujo");
            }
            i++;
        });
        this.flipACard();
    },
    flipACard: function() {
        $("#remDeck").click();
    }
})
```

Presumably you `.pop()` (or `.shift()`) cards off `remainingDeck` at some point? You could possibly do so on flipping, in which case the `i` counter is unnecessary.